# how to load just a few rows of .xls file with phpexcel?

Tags: php, csv, converters, phpexcel

I have a trouble with converting a .xls file (Excel) to CSV in [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

All works fine until comes some Big file. My php script just exceeds the memory limit and blows up. I cannot use more than 64MB because of the specifics of the computer. I'm running Apache on it.
We need to find a solution.

I think I have to tell *PHPExcel* to load just a few lines of Excel than convert it to small CSV, save it, free the used memory and so on with the rest of the file until it's done...

What you think about? Can we find the more accurate way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options for saving memory with PHPExcel. The main two are:

- cell caching, described in section 4.2.1 of the developer
  documentation,

  This allows you to reduce the memory overhead for each cell that is read from the file
- Chunking, described in section 4.3 of the User Documentation for
  Readers

  This allows you to read small ranges of rows and
  columns from a file, rather than the whole worksheet